# Number of sets which are subsets

Tags: combinatorics

Where $W_1 = \{2,3,4\},\ W_2 = \{7,8,9\} \ \ \text{and} \ \ W_3 = \{12,13,14\}.$

How many non-empty sets are there which are a subset of $W_1$ or a subset of $W_2$ or a subset of $W_3$?

Is the answer 7 or 21 or could it be both (since we're not told in which sense "or" is used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean when you think the answer could be $7$, but the way I see it the answer can only be $21$.

Given a non-empty set, you are supposed to ask "Is this a subset of $W_1$ or a subset of $W_2$ or a subset of $W_3$?" There are $21$ sets for which the answer is "yes".